# Ajax jquery not being able to pass parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to make a mashup application that gets json output from a restful webservice. the mashup application fetches latitude and longitude data from json response and then points it in an embedded good map.

```html
<html>
<form> 
  Post Code:<br> 
  <input type="text" id="postcode"><br> 
  <button onclick="getdata()">Submit</button>
</form>

<h1>Location on Google Map</h1>

<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getdata() {
    var value1 = $("input#postcode").val();
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=" + value1,
      "type": "POST",
      "method": "GET"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      data = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(data['4000']['Latitude']);
      var lat = data['4000']['Latitude'];
      var lng = data['4000']['Longitude'];
      init(lat, lng);
    });

    function init(lat, lng) {
      latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 20,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=getdata"></script>
</html>
```

However I am unable to pass different values to the parameters 'postcode' in 
"http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=". The values passed should be like 4010,4011 etc

Comment: Please take care to format code in your questions properly. This was, frankly, an unreadable mess before I edited it

Comment: `"type": "POST", method": "GET"` Type is an alies for method for older versions of jQuery. You should remove it.

Comment: removed.still not working

Comment: @MarkBaijens the main issue for me is .When i pass something as url:"http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=4010" it works. however i want to pass values of parameter taken from a text field as written in code

Comment: @PiushGoutam That's why I put it as comment. Won't solve your issue but you have both `POST` and `GET` defined. You shouldn't do this.

Comment: Are you getting any notable errors? Usually when you parse data via ajax, you just define the method, and then go on to fetching that accordingly to whatever method you're using. You do not have to parse it into the url, as you already defined a method that you are using, and regarding what url it is.

Comment: So basically, you define your method, `GET` / `POST`, and you define the url to which the data will be parsed to. If you are using a `GET` method, then you will not have to manually concatenate the variable to the url, as the variable will already be parsed as the defined method if that makes sense.

Comment: the variable i am trying to parse along is a key or a refernce value to a json type output from a RESTful api hosted locally

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=getdata"></script>` is being initiated AFTER your custom script. The google maps api should be declared BEFORE your code. Place it above your `<script>` tags containing the custom code